# Load data to gridview correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How about friends I'm trying to load an excel file ah a gridview but it shows me the following error I hope you can help me

[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAiXQ.png)

I am using Visual Basic with asp.net this is the code

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ASPxButton1.Click

    If ASPxUploadControl1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0 Then
        Dim file As UploadedFile = ASPxUploadControl1.UploadedFiles(0)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

       
        Using stream As Stream = file.FileContent
            Using reader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please paste the error message instead of linking to a picture

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are TWO installs via nuget you need.

these 2:

[image]

So once you installed both above, then you can use AsDataSet() like this:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using mystream As Stream = FileUpload1.FileContent
        Using myreader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(mystream)

            Dim conf = New ExcelDataSetConfiguration With {
                .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration With {
                .UseHeaderRow = True
                }
            }

            dt = myreader.AsDataSet().Tables(0)
        End Using
    End Using

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Alberto kept giving me the same error in the same line and I already have the two installations that you recommended to me. What do you think it is?